# Get preloader to show on button click

Tags: javascript, html, gif

I want to have a preloader for when my backend is loading for a long time, this is what ive done:

```
    <form action='#' method='post'>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p class='recP'>What have you watched?</p>
            <p><input class='BigBox' type='text' name ='animeChoice' placeholder='Type here...' /></p>
            <p class="howManyTxt"> How many animes do you want recommended?</p>
            <div class='Form'>
                <p><input class='numBox' type='number' name = 'howMany' placeholder='0'></p>
                <p><input class='subBox' type='submit' value='Submit'/></p>
            </div>
    </form>
    <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/giphy.gif" class="loaderimg" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#createReport").submit(function (event) {
        $("img.loaderimg").show(); 
        event.preventDefault(); 
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

The gif is always showing, I want it to only show up when I click.

Thank you

Comment: So hide it with css....

Comment: Hide it first with css?

Comment: You haven’t really provided much to show what you have tried to do. This is simply a post with your code, and a polite request (missing final punctuation) to provide you with an answer, nothing more. Stack Overflow is not a problem-solving service; it is a site for exchanging knowledge. Provide some of yours, and the community will reply with theirs.

Answer (score 0):

Your `form` doesn't have an `id` of `createReport` so your `.submit` handler won't run because no item matches that selector.

Also, you need to set the image to be hidden by default, which a simple CSS selector can do.

```css
img.loaderimg { display:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action='#' method='post' id="createReport">
        <p class='recP'>What have you watched?</p>
            <p><input class='BigBox' type='text' name ='animeChoice' placeholder='Type here...' /></p>
            <p class="howManyTxt"> How many animes do you want recommended?</p>
            <div class='Form'>
                <p><input class='numBox' type='number' name = 'howMany' placeholder='0'></p>
                <p><input class='subBox' type='submit' value='Submit'/></p>
            </div>
    </form>
    <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/giphy.gif" class="loaderimg" />
    <script>
        $("#createReport").submit(function (event) {
        $("img.loaderimg").show(); 
        event.preventDefault(); 
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the only issue is when I click the button it doesn't do what it used to like it doesn't "talk" to my back end. The only thing that happens is the loading gif shows up. I am using flask maybe it has to do with that. Any ideas as to why this is happening

Comment: What is your back end supposed to do exactly? judging by the code you shared its only supposed to show the loading gif. and since your action attribute is empty it's not supposed to do anything.

Comment: Basically, I use Flask to fetch what is in the text box when the button is clicked and the text is used as an argument for a python function

Comment: I eneded up removing the prevent Default and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Add `style = "display:none"` attribute to your image and it should hide it, unless `show()` function is applied to it.